# Linq Query with .Any condition returns nullreference exception

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, iqueryable

I have the following function that returns results from the database based on LINQ Expressions:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
```

When I try pulling data from the function while using the `.Any` function from a list I get a null reference exception.

However when I pull the data without that specific condition and use the same `.Any` function in a for each loop everything works correctly.

Here is the call trying to use the `.Any` function which does not work:

```
var ppcReports = repository.FindAll<PPCReport>(
    x => x.ClientId == clientId && 
    (campaigns.Any(c=> c.Id == x.CampaignId))
).ToList();
```

And the way it does work properly:

```
var ppcReports = repository.FindAll<PPCReport>(
    x => x.ClientId == clientId).ToList();

foreach (var item in ppcReports)
{
    if (campaigns.Any(c => c.Id == item.CampaignId))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I was wondering why was this happening, am I doing something wrong is it just not possible to filter the results before the query finished?

By calling `.ToList()` before filtering the results it does work, so I suppose I cannot do such an operation on an `IQueryable<T>` implementation?

```
var ppcReports = repository.
    FindAll<PPCReport>(x => x.ClientId == clientId).
    ToList().
    Where(w => campaigns.Any(c => c.Id == w.CampaignId)).
    ToList();
```

Comment: Null exception? Sql doesn't throw that. Is `campaigns` a local sequence? The first snippet always use this. The second use it only if FindAll return non empty enumerable. Edit: after your edit I'm almost sure that `campaigns` is null. In the first code linq is trying to make a query with it (it will fail anyway since it is local sequence). In the second code you probably don't enter the loop.

Comment: Did you trace sql request to database (from ef)? By the way, don't use ToList() to iterate IQueriable, use ToArray()

Comment: campaigns is a local List<PPCCampaign> populated list already from the database, what I fail to understand is why it returns a null exception when the list is populated and being used with the Any method which just checks if there's any element in that list so it should not return null exception eitherway.

I am using NHibernate in this case, I did not try to trace the sql to the database, I will try that later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like those who commented, I'm surprised that you got a NullReferenceException rather than a complaint about not being able to compile that statement to SQL. However, the following code should let you do this in 1 query (and will do all filtering in SQL):

```
var campaignIds = (campaigns ?? Enumerable.Empty<Campaign>())
    .Select(c => c.Id);
var ppcReports = repository
    .FindAll<PPCReport>(pr => pr.ClientId == clientId
        && campaignIds.Contains(pr.CampaignId))
    .ToList();
```

This should work in both EF and Linq-to-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Queryable.Any() returns an ArgumentNullException when the source is null, as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb343630(v=vs.110).aspx